# Ideal Font Size depending upon @media tags

Tags: html, css, fonts

Here are some media tags I've used to make site responsive.

```
@media all and (min-width:960px) and (max-width: 1024px){}

@media all and (min-width:769px) and (max-width: 959px){}

@media all and (min-width:569px) and (max-width: 768px){}

@media all and (min-width:481px) and (max-width: 568px){}

@media all and (min-width:321px) and (max-width: 480px) {}

@media all and (min-width:0px) and (max-width: 320px){}
```

Right now I'm using 16px font size on every size of screens from mobile devices to Desktops. I was wondering how should I change the font size depending upon these @media tags.

What would be the ideal font size as per these tags?

Thank You . . .

Comment: Ideal font size depends on many factors, including the user's preferences. E.G. people with bad eyesight may need a larger font size then people with 20/20 vision. So, voting to close as opinion based. That said, have you considered using `vw` for a unit?

Comment: @MrLister no sir, i just used 16px everywhere. Should I reduce the font size to 12 or 14px for small devices?

Comment: Your queries are correct, but SO isn't place to take advice about what font size you need for each...

Comment: Flagged as Opinion Based.